# Django url from a huge list of words from a file

Tags: django

I have a file with 60,000 words, I need the url to be valid only when it contains any of the words in that file

```
url(r'^site/KEYWORD/$', 'mysite.views.home')
```

so basically I need KEYWORD to be one of the words present in that file.

I know that we can use the pipe for multiple words but the list too large to do that

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that in the URL; do it in the view.

```
def my_view(request, word):
    if word not in WORDS:
        raise Http404()
```

For best performance, WORDS should be a set defined at module level.

Answer (score 0):

At first, make `keyword` a URL parameter:

```
url(r'^site/(?P<keyword>\w+)/$', 'mysite.views.home')
```

Then in your view you can do something like this:

```
def home(request, keyword=None):
    if keyword in open('./words.txt').read():
        ...

    raise Http404()
```

But this **is not** a good way of doing it because on every request you will open and read the whole file. The solution is to store these words in a constant module-level variable and read the file once.

Some thing like this:

```
WORDS = open('./words.txt').read()
```

And then in your view:

```
if keyword in WORDS:
    ...
```